# String manipulation and concatenating in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a String like:

```
"/system/path/513/b02/36a/66ea2557[*,0].swf,16"
```

I'm using Ruby on Rails for my application. I am trying to make 16 urls by appending 1-16 to the end of 66ea2557  to get something like:

```
"/system/path/513/b02/36a/66ea25571.swf"
"/system/path/513/b02/36a/66ea25572.swf"
..
"/system/path/513/b02/36a/66ea255715.swf"
"/system/path/513/b02/36a/66ea255716.swf"
```

How can I do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that:

- You're given `"/system/path/513/b02/36a/66ea2557[*,0].swf,16"` from somewhere perhaps out of your control and it needs to be parsed
- The number `16` at the end of the string won't necessarily be the same every time and signifies the number of urls you need
- You don't need the `[*,0]` part of the string for anything and it doesn't necessarily signify anything

I came up with:

```
string = "/system/path/513/b02/36a/66ea2557[*,0].swf,16"
base_path, _, file_extension, num_urls = string.split(/(\[\*,0\])|,/)
# => ["/system/path/513/b02/36a/66ea2557", "[*,0]", ".swf", "16"]
(1..num_urls.to_i).map { |i| "#{base_path}#{i}#{file_extension}" }
# => ["/system/path/513/b02/36a/66ea25571.swf",
      "/system/path/513/b02/36a/66ea25572.swf",
      ...
      "/system/path/513/b02/36a/66ea255716.swf"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(1..16).each do |i|
  puts "/system/path/513/b02/36a/66ea2557#{i}.swf"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try simple looping. Something like:

```
#test.rb

arr = Array.new();
for i in 1..16
    arr[i-1] = "/system/path/513/b02/36a/66ea2557" + i.to_s;
end

puts arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [String#%](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-25):

```
path = "/system/path/513/b02/36a/66ea2557%s.swf"
(1..16).map {|index| path % index}
```